# Is this a clearfix float? I can't get my footer to be at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I want my footer to be at the bottom of the page after the content on each page (not fixed)
I read the post about creating a sticky footer, and I tried:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

But my footer is still right after the image which was floated.  I put in a clearfix but that didn't solve it.  What am I doing wrong, here is the link:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is the height of "main-content".

Remove it, and set:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

And "padding-bottom" on your "main-content" with the same (or more) height of your footer, for spacing.

A complete example can found at [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
```

gets it to bottom of window but if your page is longer you get a result like your page..

Instead you could set it to fixed, wrap the other content and leave  75px space underneath for your footer, [check this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) ;

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
```